# Connection between "Recalls" and "Unique Device Identifier" databases

Tags: openfda

I would like to easily link a field on the "Unique Device Identifier" database to a field on the "Recalls" database, so I can easily see more information of a device/lead which has a recall.
Which field would it be?

Thank you

Comment: Where are these databases? How is this on topic for open data?

Comment: Hi James! I meant this databases:
https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/recall/
https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/udi/

Answer (score 0):

You can link based on the field, openfda.device_name, which is common between the "Recalls" and the "Unique Device Identifier" APIs

Comment: Indeed that is a common field. However, it is not a unique identifier, since there are multiple devices with the same openfda.device_name. Do you know about any other field which can be used?

Comment: pma_number for example, would it be a good link?